# adding linefeed to memo field type

Tags: vba, ado.net

The linefeed does not appear in access db:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\temp\a.mdb")
db.OpenRecordset("table1", dbOpenTable) 
.AddNew ' create a new record 
.Fields("memofield") = "123" + chr(13)+"line2"
.Update ' stores the new record
```

Comment: Have you tried using the vbCrLf constant?

Comment: Great! but how to convert excel crlf:s to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, ,but I believe you need to use a combination of chr 13 & 10:

```
.Fields("memofield") = "123" + chr(13) + chr(10) + "line2"
```